# Override Standard Assert Messaging in Pytest Assert

Tags: python, testing, pytest, assert

I'm using Pytest to test some SQL queries my team runs programmatically over time.

My SQL queries are lists of JSONs - one JSON corresponds to one row of data.

I've got a function that diffs the JSON key:value pairs so that we can point to exactly which values are different for a given row.  Ideally, I'd output a list of these diffs *instead* of the standard output of an assert statement, which ends up looking clunky and not-very-useful for the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pytest give us the hook [`pytest_assertrepr_compare`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#defining-your-own-assertion-comparison) to add a custom explanation about why an assertion failed.

You can create a class to wrap the JSON string and implement your comparator algorithm overloading the equal operator.

```
class JSONComparator:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # Here your algorithm to compare two JSON strings
        ...

        # If they are different, save that information
        # We will need it later
        self.diff = "..."

        return True

# Put the hook in conftest.py or import it in order to make pytest aware of the hook.
def pytest_assertrepr_compare(config, op, left, right):

    if isinstance(left, JSONComparator) and op == "==":
        # Return the diff inside an array.
        return [left.diff]

# Create a reference as an alias if you want
compare = JSONComparator
```

#### Usage

```
def test_somethig():
    original = '{"cartoon": "bugs"}'
    expected = '{"cartoon": "bugs"}'

    assert compare(original) == expected
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python built-in capability to show custom exception message:

```
assert response.status_code == 200, "My custom message: actual status code {}".format(response.status_code)
```

Check it out: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively

Comment: This does exactly what I want!  There's one other piece here: I'd like to suppress the standard assert output entirely (sometimes, the diffs are very large, and when the assert to show the diff on top of my custom message, the logging is effectively rendered useless).  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using logging module?

Comment: I'm not right now.  Since I'm running this job in a scheduler (Azkaban), which spits out the stdout of pytest's tests, I can see the logs directly in a browser.

Comment: Yeah but you I suggest you to take outputs from logging module, for this question you can built the helper assert functions.

Comment: Updated the answer.