# python assert: object comparison: print more meaningful failure message automatically

Tags: python, assert

Let us say I have some type `Anga` in which I've overridden these: `__eq__ __str__`. With pytest, failures such as `assert a2 - 1 == a1`  yield this unhelpful message:

`E     assert <jyotisha.panchaanga.temporal.zodiac.angas.Anga object at 0x7f2ab24dfe50> == <jyotisha.panchaanga.temporal.zodiac.angas.Anga object at 0x7f2ab2507dc0>`

Is there some method I can override in `Anga` so as get more meaningful failure messages automatically (without having to do `assert a2 - 1 == a1, "meaningful message"` or `assert str(a2-1) == str(a1)`)?

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438480/149900): Try using [**`pytest_assertrepr_compare`**](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#defining-your-own-explanation-for-failed-assertions)